# Android Orientation with Video

Tags: android, video, orientation

I am just developing one Android app, in which we have to capture the video. Now user will capture the video in portrait view but while it will play, it will automatically play in landscape.

i.e. video is capture in portrait view, though it will play in landscape view. when i will check in memory card, video is still captured in portrait view and also while playing video from memory card, it will play in portrait view.

I have checked, manifest file and seems all files are fine.

Please let me know if any one have any idea.

Regards,
Keyur Satyadev

Comment: i am already face this problem